# SNPE Model conversion: Syntax for model input with 0 dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, qualcomm, snpe

I'm using SNPE to convert a NN model from `.tflite` format to `.dlc`. Usually models I have converted easily work as it's a simple matter of specifying the dimensions of each input as parameters to the `snpe-tflite-to-dlc` tool featured in SNPE. However, my current model features 2 inputs which are of no dimensions at all. See this screenshot from my Netron visualisation of the model:

[image: 2 inputs without any dimensions]

The [documentation](https://developer.qualcomm.com/sites/default/files/docs/snpe/tools.html#tools_snpe-tflite-to-dlc) concerning this tool does not mention what sort of input should be specified in this case, only giving an example of multiple inputs. My command currently looks like this:

```
snpe-tflite-to-dlc \
        --input_network facebook_denoiser.tflite \
        --input_dim audio "1,1,100000" \
        --input_dim arg0 "" \
        --input_dim arg1 "" \
        --input_dim arg2 "390,1,768" \
        --input_dim arg3 "1,768" \
        --input_dim arg4 "1,768" \
        --input_dim arg5 "390,1,768"
```

Running it does not work, and I have tried various other similiar ways such as omitting `arg0` and `arg1` completely, or setting them as 0, but the tool just throws a NoneType error (which usually means that the parameters were not correctly formatted).

Does anyone know how to convert such a model?